# Python assignment in just one line

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python and I saw this form to give values to a list

```
color= ['red' if v == 0 else 'green' for v in y]
```

But if I try to do it with 3 number, for example

```
color= ['red' if v == 0 elif v == 1 'blue' else 'green' for v in y]
```

is that possible or do I have to do it like this:

```
color = ['none']*len(y)
for i in range(0,len(color)):
    if y[i] == 0:
        color[i] = 'red'
    elif y[i] == 1:
        color[i] = 'blue'
    else:
        color[i] = 'green'
```

because this form is not as easy to write as the other one.
Thank you.

Comment: Keep up your effort and remember you will always get help in SO if you've shown effort from your part which you have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but you have to modify your syntax slightly (and use `else` instead of the `elif`s):

```
color= ['red' if v == 0 else 'blue' if v == 1  else 'green' for v in y]
```

**Example**:

```
y = [1,0,2,3,0,1]    
color= ['red' if v == 0 else 'blue' if v == 1  else 'green' for v in y]

>>> color
['blue', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'blue']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary instead.

**If** you could restructure your questions with more details the answer would make more sense I think!

```
colors = {
    0: 'red',
    1: 'blue'
}

color = [colors.get(v, 'green') for v in y]
```

---

Dictionary class has a built-in function named .get() that accepts a key and a default value if the key is not found. `colors.get(v, 'green')` translates into: give me the value of key `v` in dictionary `colors`, however if not found, give me `'green'`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `v` has integer values, you can use the values to index into a list or tuple of the color names as:

```
>>> y = [0,1,2,1,1,0,2,2]
>>> [ ('red', 'blue')[i] if i in (0,1) else 'green' for i in y]
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'green']
```

Similar to the dictionary approaches, this approach could be extended to a longer list of items pretty easily, but you don't have to create a separate dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary like so:

```
color_codes = { 0: 'red',
1: 'blue',
2: 'green'
}

color = [color_codes[v] for v in y]
```